# How to validate array inputs using proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation and Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, laravel, validation, laravel-5

Hi I'm trying to validate an array input and select like this:

```
<td width="23%">                                            
{!!Form::select('mmscod_id[]',['' => '- Seleccione un material -'] +$mat,null,['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'mmscod_id'])!!}    
</td>

<td width="17%">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="vtcanp[]"/> 

</td>
<td width="17%">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio" name="vtprep[]"/>
</td>
```

I'm using the [proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) for client-side validation. For the back-end I use Laravel's Form request.

I also use the method of this site: [How To: Validate an array of form fields with Laravel](https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/) but it doesn't work and throws errors:

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5gcf.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGU5r.png)

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that these elements are created dynamically
Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Laravel supports validating array inputs. You need to use this convention to validate array item.

```
$rules = [
    'vtcanp.*' => 'required',
];
```

For example:

This is my custom request class

```
class InvoiceRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules =[
            'client' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required',
            'total' => 'required',
            'discount' => 'required',
            'item.*' => 'required',
            'rate.*' => 'required',
            'quantity.*' => 'required',


        ];


        return $rules;
    }
}
```

And in the view added

```
{!! JsValidator::formRequest('App\Http\Requests\InvoiceRequest') !!}
```

These validate and show the error message with position of input array that I dynamically added to the view.

Comment: I tried and doesn't validate the client side. I think the proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation doesn't support this validation rule yet.

Comment: For me its working for dynamically created input fields.I am working on Laravel 5.2

Comment: With Laravel 5.5 and JsValidation 2.2.1, this answer works fine for me BUT it will fail if I provide an 'array' type validation, e.g. **'rate' => 'required|array|min:1'**. This breaks JsValidation when there is only 1 element in the array (JsValidation see's it an a single value, not array in this case)